# What is the B2C Custom Policy Syntax to send query values over the URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to send a REST request to the following URL from a B2C custom policy:

```http
https://some-url/api/searchMe/searchCriteria/:searchCriteriaId
```

My REST policy looks like this

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-SearchCriteria">
    <DisplayName>API to attach json payload</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://some-url/api/searchMe/searchCriteria</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="searchCriteriaId" />
    </InputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

`searchCriteriaId` is a `String` data type of user input type `TextBox`

```xml
<ClaimType Id="searchCriteriaId">
    <DisplayName>Search Criteria</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Search Criteria</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

In this scenario `searchCriteriaId` is equal to "342820348302" so I was expecting the url coming from B2C to look like this "https://some-url/api/searchMe/searchCriteria/342820348302"
This doesn't seem to be happening. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your URL variables/claims with curly braces and they need to match the name of the claim from your `InputClaims`.

So, for your example where your claim is named `searchCriteriaId`, instead of:

```xml
<Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://some-url/api/searchMe/searchCriteria</Item>
```

You would have:

```xml
<Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://some-url/api/searchMe/{searchCriteriaId}</Item>
```

See also the `SendClaimsIn` section of the [REST API Metadata documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata).

Comment: Thank you. I missed that small change. My `ServiceUrl` turned out like this `<Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://some-url/api/searchMe/searchCriteria/{searchCriteriaId}</Item>`